# tar a .tgz but autoconf doesn't configure properly

Tags: ubuntu, tar, configure, autoconf

Using Ubuntu, have the file `clhep-2.1.2.4.tgz`
The instructions say to "unwind the source code tar ball and autoconf and automake will already have been run." it then says to do the standard "/configure --prefix=[path]", "make", "make install"...

So I did

```
$tar -xvzf clhep-2.1.2.4.tgz
```

then inside the resultant `2.1.2.4/CLHEP/` is where I should do the `./configure part`... however `./configure` isn't there, only ./configure.ac which I learned from some research should produce `./configure`... Problem is when I run `./configure.ac` I get:

```
./configure.ac: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token '2.59'

./configure.ac: line 11: 'AC_PREREQ(2.59)'
```

I'm positive I have `autoconf2.59` and I've run all my updates and upgrades, but I'm clueless on how to fix this since I didn't write the script and I have no idea why it's a syntax error.

Comment: It's a syntax error because you're not supposed to run `configure.ac`; it's not a shell script.

Comment: So when it says to do `./configure`, what should I do since that executable doesn't exist? or should I just assume it all worked properly?

Comment: You said you looked in `2.1.2.4/CLHEP/`. Is there a `configure` in `2.1.2.4/`?

Comment: There is not. Inside `2.1.2.4` there is only the `CLHEP` directory

Comment: Then I'd try running `autoreconf` in the `CLHEP` directory.

Comment: ... and file a bug report about the broken instructions.

Comment: The instructions are not broken.  The package is broken.  No user should ever be required to run autoreconf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like `configure` script was not produced yet. You can generate it via:

```
$ autoreconf -fis
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the documentation is a bit old for this package (the website documentation takes you to install infor for version 2.0 only). I think this had to do with a change to Cmake. You should find the correct instructions in `INSTALL.autoconf` to help generate the configure file, or alternatively, use the cmake install instructions in `INSTALL.cmake`

Both those files are in the CLHEP directory. Anyway, it seems what was missing was a call to `./bootstrap`